# Blazor - Make InputText fit to parent container

Tags: html, css, blazor

I would like to make a form with multiple InputText on the same line.
But the InputText width is always 203px. 
How can I specify the InputText to fit to the parent width ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label>Address</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="Address.Postcode" placeholder="Postcode" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="Address.HouseNumber" placeholder="House Nb" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <InputText @bind-Value="Address.Street" placeholder="Street" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `style="width: 100%"` to the input

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label>Address</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
        <InputText style="width: 100%;" @bind-Value="Address.Postcode" placeholder="Postcode" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
        <InputText style="width: 100%;" @bind-Value="Address.HouseNumber" placeholder="House Nb" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <InputText style="width: 100%;" @bind-Value="Address.Street" placeholder="Street" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Don't know why I haven't think about